# How to avoid N+1 queries with Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ransack, rails-bullet

I've beeen using [Ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) in one of my projects and also using [Bullet](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet) to
spot some N+1 queries in my controllers. However, I'm not quite sure how to accomplish that while using Ransack.
There are two models involved, `Patch` and `Image`. And a `Patch` `has_one` `Image`.
The action code is the follow:

```
  def index
    @q = Patch.search(params[:q])
    @patches = @q.result(distinct: true).order("code DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
  end
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You can try @q = Patch.includes(:image).search(params[:q])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working to me in a project.
  def index
    @q = Client.includes(zone: :user).ransack(params[:q])
    @clients = @q.result.page(params[:page]).decorate
  end

In your case should be

```
def index
    @q = Patch.includes(:image).search(params[:q])
    @patches = @q.result(distinct: true).order("code DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
end
```